# Can you give me some examples on using telerik without using kendo?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, telerik-mvc

I know this is a subjective question and will most probably be closed but desperate times lead to desperate measures. I tried searching for examples of telerik for hours but I could not find a simple program that I could understand. I am new to mvc and haven't worked on telerik. What I have to do is create a user table using sql server and then display the user tables in a grid. That much part I have done. Now I want to do create, edit and delete on the rows by using a pop up dialog box and it should also have validations. Kind of like [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/opiy) example. As of now I have only created a grid and the coding is as follows:

User.cs

```
namespace MvcTelerikGrid.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<User> list = new List<User>();
        using (DetailsEntities dc = new DetailsEntities())
        {
            list = dc.Users.OrderBy(a => a.UserId).ToList();
        }
        return View(list);
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@model IEnumerable<MvcTelerikGrid.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@{
    Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.FirstName).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.LastName).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Address).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.City).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Email).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.PhoneNo).Width(100);
    })
    .Pageable(a => a.PageSize(2))
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .Render();
}

@(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group=> group.Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.windows7.css").Combined(true).Compress(true)))
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar())
```

Please do help me.

Comment: This probably will be closed, but what you could think about doing is using Telerik to render a button that contains a link with the individual ID of the item in each row, link that to a partialresult action so that you can return a basic page with no layout. Using JS, you can then create and populate a modal dialog (with your partial result) on the button click via AJAX.

Comment: @Sippy I haven't worked on AJAX yet so I don't have any idea on how to do it.

Comment: Ah I see how it works, what is it you're confused about with that example? Seems quite straightforward. Maybe I can explain :)

Comment: @Sippy I have no idea how to go forward with this project. I have given a link in the question where there is an example using kendo. I want similar output without using kendo

Comment: Is Telerik a requirement? I don't actually know TelerikUI, but from what I've seen you could make it much simpler by using something like Grid.MVC

Comment: @Sippy Telerik is a requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84369/discussion-between-sippy-and-itaws).